# Assigning values to overwrite python array

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to assign new values to an array based on whether or not the stored value is <3. Coming from an R background this is how I would do it, but this gives me a syntax error in Python. What am I doing wrong, and what is the Python approach?

```
eurx=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,'a',8]
sma50=3

tw=eurx
tw[eurx<sma50]=-1
tw[eurx>=sma50]=1
tw[(tw!=1)||(tw!=-1)]=0
print(tw)
```

GOAL:

```
-1
-1
1
1
1
1
1
0
1
```

Comment: That is not an array, that is a list

Comment: Also, this never makes a copy in Python, if that was your intent: `tw=eurx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is "too much R". A pythonic way would be to use functional filtering:

```
>>> map(lambda i: -2*int(i<sma50)+1 if type(i) == int else 0, eurx)
[-1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

Or just a simple for-loop with a few ifs:

```
>>> for i in eurx:
...   if type(i) != int: 
...     print 0
...   else: 
...     print -2*int(i<sma50)+1
... 
-1
-1
1
1
1
1
1
0
1
```

In general: don't try to guess the syntax. It's very simple, just read through some tutorials (e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming)

**Edit**: the `int` conversion hack works as follows: you know you can convert bool to int, right?

```
>>> int(True)
1
>>> int(False)
0
```

If `i<sma50` evaluates to True, `int(i<sma50)` will be 1. So yor numbers now are converted to ones if `i` is smaller than `sma50` and to zeros otherwise. But apparently you want the values `(-1, 1)` instead of `(1, 0)`. Just apply the transform `-2x+1` and you're done!

Comment: Could you explain the reason for the -2 ? Based on some googling for map and lambda it doesnt seem to be needed by either of those

Comment: Right, it's not required. You can insert another `if` to get the same result without the bool-to-int conversion hack.

Comment: The first code is not readable, and if you use `map` with a lambda, you might as well use a list comprehension. The second example doesn't return  or define anything, it just prints elements.

Answer (score 1):

Your desired syntax is pretty close to what you'd write in [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/).

The heterogeneous list doesn't make it easy, but here's an example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> eurx=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,'a',8]
>>> sma50 = 3
>>> tw = np.array([i if isinstance(i, int) else np.nan for i in eurx])
>>> tw
array([  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,  nan,   8.])
>>> tw[tw < sma50] = -1
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
>>> tw[tw >= sma50] = 1
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater_equal
>>> tw
array([ -1.,  -1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,  nan,   1.])
>>> tw[np.isnan(tw)] = 0
>>> tw
array([-1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.])
```